# Deploy and set Ispac connectionstring property in the Connection Manager tab with Powershell

Tags: powershell

I can successfully deploy the ssis project with powershell using the code below however, i also wanted to set the connectionstring property (at the project level) in the Connection Managers tab. i tried to search but can't find any sources. can someone please help?[image]

```
# Variables
$SSISNamespace = "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices"

$TargetServerName = "localhost"
$TargetFolderName = "Project1Folder"
$ProjectFilePath = "C:\Projects\Integration Services Project1\Integration Services Project1\bin\Development\Integration Services Project1.ispac"
$ProjectName = "Integration Services Project1"

# Load the IntegrationServices assembly
$loadStatus = [System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.IntegrationServices, "+
    "Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL")

# Create a connection to the server
$sqlConnectionString = `
    "Data Source=" + $TargetServerName + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$sqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection $sqlConnectionString

# Create the Integration Services object
$integrationServices = New-Object $SSISNamespace".IntegrationServices" $sqlConnection

# Get the Integration Services catalog
$catalog = $integrationServices.Catalogs["SSISDB"]

# Create the target folder
$folder = New-Object $SSISNamespace".CatalogFolder" ($catalog, $TargetFolderName,
    "Folder description")
$folder.Create()

Write-Host "Deploying " $ProjectName " project ..."

# Read the project file and deploy it
[byte[]] $projectFile = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($ProjectFilePath)
$folder.DeployProject($ProjectName, $projectFile)

Write-Host "Done."
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSIS configuring parameter value from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42688264/ssis-configuring-parameter-value-from-powershell)

Comment: @GuentherSchmitz not a duplicate. the link you provided is for setting the parameter value of the ssis project not the connectionstring for Connection Managers

Comment: I already got the solution. :)

Comment: mind sharing it by answering your own question?

Answer (score 2):

got this working. just need to set the value for CM.ConfigurationDatabase.ConnectionString parameter.

```
$Project = $folder.Projects[$ProjectName]

$cm_value = "test"

$Project.Parameters["CM.ConfigurationDatabase.ConnectionString"].Set([Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.IntegrationServices.ParameterInfo+ParameterValueType]::Literal, $cm_value)
```